# Python MySql record delete two digit id?

Tags: python, mysql

Apparently once the record's ID in MySQL is more than one digit, the usual:

```
c.execute("DELETE FROM <table_name> WHERE id = %s, "thwart(str(element['id'])))
```

stops working.

What could cause this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter to execute should be an iterable with your query parameters. Replace:

```
c.execute("DELETE FROM <table_name> WHERE id = %s", thwart(str(element['id'])))
```

with:

```
myid = thwart(str(element['id']))
c.execute("DELETE FROM <table_name> WHERE id = %s", (myid, ))
```

Comment: 2 hours of my life! :) Thank you, SOLVED!